# PHP Swiftmailer receiver's name from database in body

Tags: php, database, email, foreach, swiftmailer

Hello i am using Swiftmailer to send a newsletter and i want to use their name from the database at the beginning of the mail in the body i have succeeded in getting a name in the body of the mail and in the receiver but it only grabs the first entry from the database when i want the name in the body it doesn't use the 2nd or third

```
    foreach ($result as $row) {         
    if ($_POST['test_or_live'] == 'live') { 
        $email[] = array($row['mail'] => $row['firstname']); //for the mail address and firstname in the receiver. works
        $firstname[] = $row['firstname']; //for the firstname in the body. not working
    }
```

And this is the foreach i use to send and put the firstname in the body

```
foreach ($email as $mail => $name) {

    foreach ($firstname as $value) {
        $content = str_replace('firstname',$value,$content);
    }

    if (is_int($mail)) {
        $message->setTo($name);
    } 

    else {
        $message->setTo(array($mail => $name));
    }

    $message->setBody($content,'text/html');
    $numSent += $mailer->send($message, $failedRecipients);
}
```

So how do i get it to loop over all the names and send the correct name to the correct mail address

Answer (score 0):

In your loop

```
foreach ($firstname as $value) {
    $content = str_replace('firstname',$value,$content);
}
```

you are replacing your template placeholder 'firstname' in the first iteration with a name.

Since the firstname is provided in your outer loop as `$name`

```
foreach ($email as $mail => $name)
```

you don't need the `$firstname[]` array:

```
foreach ($email as $mail => $name) {
    $content = str_replace('firstname',$name,$content);
    ...
```

Comment: When i do that it outputs 'Array'

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your `$email` array?

Comment: $email[] = array($row['mail'] => $row['firstname']); was in the original question but here you go or do you mean what is in it from the database?   the firstname in the database contains 'hello' and 'bye'

Comment: Sorry, my bad, So does it look like `Array([0] => Array([mail1] => firstname1), [1] => Array([mail2] => firstname2)...`?

Comment: No it just literally says 'Array'

Comment: I mean in the `foreach ($email as $mail => $name) {`loop a sample for `$mail` and `$name`

Comment: it says array to string conversion from the content str_replace

Comment: Pls. provide a sample for `$mail` and `$name`in the `foreach ($email as $mail => $name)`loop